# For integers $n>1$ , $k$ , does there exist matrix $A$ with integer entries and first row $(1,2,...,n)$ such that $\det A=k$?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, determinant

Let $n >1$ be an integer , then is it true that for any integer $k$ , there exist a matrix $A \in M(n,\mathbb Z)$ with first row of $A$ as $(1,2,...,n)$ such that $\det A=k$ ?

Comment: Yes. That's basically because the gcd of $1,2,\ldots,n$ is $1$.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy : could you please elaborate ...

Comment: @user228169 See e.g. here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1411324

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the transpose of
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccccccc}
1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0\\
3 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
4 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \ldots & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
n-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 1 & 0\\
n & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & k\\
\end{array}\right)
$$

Comment: Now I see your answer ... how about taking an upper triangular matrix with first row as desired and the diagonal entries all $1$ except the $n$ th diagonal entry being $k$ ?

Comment: @user228169 this is exactly what I'm saying, I just initially wrote my matrix with first column as desired instead of first row, so I siad "take the transpose". Note that the matrix is not completely triangular

Comment: yeah , your matrix is not triangular . But the way I am saying , we can make an upper triangular matrix right ? And the determinant is just the product of diagonal entries ...

Comment: @user228169 Indeed. it is a little simpler

Comment: Thank you :) all those $0$ s in your construction triggered the idea ..